# How to duplicate image using BitmapData

Tags: c#

I had a situation to duplicate an image with the help of bitmap data, below is the code i used to do the same, am I wrong anywhere, please help me.. Try drawing this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCSoQ.png in the bmp format

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Bitmap mask = Image.FromFile("../../Data/mask.bmp") as Bitmap;
BitmapData data = mask.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, mask.Width, mask.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, mask.PixelFormat);
int bytes = Math.Abs(data.Stride) * mask.Height;
byte[] outPut = new byte[bytes];
Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, outPut, 0, bytes);

Bitmap test = new Bitmap(mask.Width, mask.Height, mask.PixelFormat);
BitmapData testData = test.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, test.Width, test.Height),
ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, test.PixelFormat);
Marshal.Copy(outPut, 0, testData.Scan0, bytes);
test.UnlockBits(testData);
test.Save("test.jpg");
}
```

Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: There is a need to make some alterations in the BitmapData of the initial image.

Comment: Not a duplicate actually, but i could not even duplicate this image. After trying the duplication, I need to try altering the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem in getting the color palette of the image through BitmapData, on replacing the color palette of the new image with the old, we could get the same image.

```
Bitmap mask = Image.FromFile("../../Data/mask.bmp") as Bitmap;
        BitmapData data = mask.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)mask.PhysicalDimension.Width, (int)mask.PhysicalDimension.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        int bytes = Math.Abs(data.Stride) * mask.Height;            
        byte[] outPut = new byte[bytes];
        Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, outPut, 0, bytes);
        Marshal.Copy(outPut, 0, data.Scan0, bytes);
        mask.UnlockBits(data);

        Bitmap test = new Bitmap(mask.Width, mask.Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        test.Palette = mask.Palette;
        BitmapData testData = test.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, mask.Width, mask.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        Marshal.Copy(outPut, 0, testData.Scan0, bytes);
        test.UnlockBits(data);
        test.Save("test.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

with the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/5ey6h79d.aspx you should get it.

```
    private void CopyImage()
    {

        // Create a new bitmap.
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("c:\\fakePhoto.jpg");

        // Lock the bitmap's bits.  
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
            bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            bmp.PixelFormat);

        // Get the address of the first line.
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
        int bytes  = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

        // Set every third value to 255. A 24bpp bitmap will look red.  
        //for (int counter = 2; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 3)
        //    rgbValues[counter] = 255;

        // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);

        // Unlock the bits.
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        // Draw the modified image.
        //e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 150);

        bmp.Save("c:\\fakePhotoCopy.jpg");

    }
```

Comment: But the output image is not same as the input image. It is altered.

Comment: I tried the same code, but the problem is, it does not work for the bmp images, Can you please have a look into the image attached to the link in my post, save that image in bmp format.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use P/Invoke, this can be done with a single copy.

```
class MyClass
{
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory", SetLastError = false)]
  public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint count);

  Bitmap _frame = null;
  BitmapData _dest = null;

  void Reinit( int width, int height, PixelFormat format )
  {
    if ( _frame != null )
    {
      _frame.Unlock(_dest);
      _frame.Dispose();
    }

    _frame = new Bitmap( width, height, format );
    _dest = _frame.LockBits( new Rectangle( 0, 0, _frame.Width, _frame.Height ), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, _frame.PixelFormat );
  }

  void CloneBitmapData( BitmapData src )
  {
    if ( _dest == null || _dest.Width != src.Width || _dest.Height != src.Height )
      Reinit( src.Width, src.Height, src.PixelFormat );

    CopyMemory( _dest.Scan0, src.Scan0, (uint)(src.Stride * src.Height) );
  }
```